# Adding property to td for textExtraction sort?

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net, tablesorter

Due to some crazy requests, I've created a .NET `GridView` with three labels inside each column (see Jan column below for example).

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <div style="float: left; width: 10px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblForecast_m1" Text='<%# _
                Eval("f_m1", "{0:#,###,0}")%>' runat="server" 
                CssClass="txtBoldSmall" Style="float: left;"></asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div style="float: right; width: 10px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblVariance_m1" Text='<%# _
                 Eval("a_m1", "{0:#,###,0}") - Eval("f_m1", "{0:#,###,0}")%>' 
                 runat="server" Style="float: left;" 
                 CssClass="txtBoldSmall"></asp:Label>
        </div>

         <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 10px;">
             <asp:Label ID="lblActual_m1" Text='<%# _
                 Eval("a_m1", "{0:#,###,0}")%>' runat="server" 
                  CssClass="txtBoldSmall" Style="float: left;"></asp:Label>
         </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I would like to be able to sort by only the third numbers (in this case, 0, 0, -20, and -14).  Keep in mind that all columns will have three numbers, ignore Feb below.

[image]

I have seen [examples](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-advanced.html) of custom textExtraction parsers that make use of a data property added directly to the `<td>`, but with this .NET approach, I don't have the best control over the generated HTML.  For example, see the `data-lastname` field added to the `td` below:

```
<td data-lastname="Jones">Maria Consuela de Los Angeles Ortiz Del Toro-Jones</td>
```

Could I use OnRowDataBound to append this HTML property directly to the `<td>` that is being generated (using the value of the `a_m1` - `f_m1` to set this property)?  Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the divs are floating all over the place, and when I made [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/1472/) I noticed I chose the wrong div, I think it would be best to just add a class name to the div that contains the data you want to sort. Something like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <div style="width: 100%">
        <div style="float: left; width: 10px;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblForecast_m1" Text='<%# _
                Eval("f_m1", "{0:#,###,0}")%>' runat="server" 
                CssClass="txtBoldSmall" Style="float: left;"></asp:Label>
        </div>

        <div class="sortme" style="float: right;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblVariance_m1" Text='<%# _
                 Eval("a_m1", "{0:#,###,0}") - Eval("f_m1", "{0:#,###,0}")%>' 
                 runat="server" Style="float: left;" 
                 CssClass="txtBoldSmall"></asp:Label>
        </div>

         <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 10px;">
             <asp:Label ID="lblActual_m1" Text='<%# _
                 Eval("a_m1", "{0:#,###,0}")%>' runat="server" 
                  CssClass="txtBoldSmall" Style="float: left;"></asp:Label>
         </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Then you can use the `textExtraction` function and target specific columns (or the entire table if every column has the same structute) with this code:

```
var getSortData = function (node) {
    return $(node).find('.sort').text();
};

$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widthFixed: true,
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns'],

    textExtraction: {
        1: getSortData,
        2: getSortData
    }

});
```

- Note: I removed the "width:10px;" from the "sortme" divs because the numbers were overflowing into the next column.